# MSSQL Merge when not matched THEN Insert ID From Source

Tags: sql-server, sql-merge

I've got problem with MERGE Statement. I am comparing 2 tables.
WHEN MATCHED UPDATE works like charm, but there's a problem with WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT clause.
I want to insert rows to daSRC (source) table but I need to have the same da_DocId as in source table.

This is simplicited query.

```
MERGE DocAnalytical daSRC
USING  (
    select 
    da_DaId, da_DocId, da_DelId, 
    FROM DocAnalytical dad
    JOIN DocElems del on dad.da_DelID=del.Del_ID 
) as dest
ON dest.da_DaId=daSRC.da_DaId --i know it's identity but normal its more complex clause
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET 
da_DocId=dadSRC.da_DocId, da_DelId=dadSRC.da_DelId

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (da_DocId, da_DelId, 
VALUES(daSRC.da_DocId, da_DelId, -- daSRC not available
);
```

Desired result:
Before

```
da_DaID     da_DocId    da_DelId     da_DaId (identity)
----------- ----------- -----------
162         5160        98
163         5160        98
164         5160        99
```

Not Matched Row

```
da_DaID     da_DocId    da_DelId
----------- ----------- -----------
300         5300        100
```

After

```
da_DaID     da_DocId    da_DelId
----------- ----------- -----------
162         5160        98
163         5160        98
164         5160        99
165         5160        100   << dad_DocId from daSRC (source)
```

Comment: da_DaID is incremental, right? da_DocId = 5160 fixed? Can not you use if/else for this purpose?

Comment: @mkRabbani yes da_DaID (identity) da_DocId fixed I can use CASE but in WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT i dont get id from source (USING xxx table)